# Windows Server HyperV Upgrade from 2012 to 2019 TTFB Latency

Tags: windows, hyper-v, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I am experiencing significant latency (15 to 20 seconds) with regard to TTFB (time to first byte) after I updated my web server from Windows Server 2012 to 2019.  The web server is virtualized and the latency only occurs when saving or retrieving images files on a separate server via a virtual directory to a networked share configured in IIS (version 10).

The shared directory contains 160,000+ image files (gif, jpg, png).  Not sure if the issue is due to the Hyper V configuration or the number of files in the shared folder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, I simply removed and re-added the network share properties on the Windows directory.  I do not know what the underlying problem was but adding and removing the share seemed to "reset" the directory.  Now there is no TTFB (time to first byte) latency when either creating or reading files.